# Hadoop namenode format not working

Tags: hadoop

I've been trying to install hadoop 2.7.0 on Ubuntu but when i enter the `hadoop namenode -format` command i get the following message:

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode

I've triple checked all the configuration files but i can't seem to find where the problem is.
I followed this tutorial : http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php
Can anyone please tell me why is this not working??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add **hadoop-hdfs-2.7.0.jar** to your hadoop classpath. Just add these lines in **$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh**:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/path/to/hadoop
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.0.jar
```

Now, stop all hadoop processes. Try to format namenode now. Post the error if you get any.